# ПРИЕХАЛ НАКАНУНЕ, ОСТАНОВИЛСЯ НА МИГ - словосочетаниями с наречием?

Tags: наречия, словосочетания

Являются ли следующие словосочетаниями с наречием:

> приехал накануне
>
> остановился на миг

Answer (score 1):

Да, приведенные словосочетания -сочетания с  наречием.

Answer (score 1):

Это глагольные словосочетания с зависимыми словами-наречиями. Правда, в "остановиться на миг" -"на миг" ещё не наречие, а наречное выражение, состоящее из существительного с предлогом, потому и пишется раздельно, а наречие - всегда слитно.

Процесс образования наречий ещё пока идёт.